# Populate choices in Choice column with values in Title column of same SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list

Is it possible to populate the choices in a Choice column with **all** of the values in the Title column of the **same** SharePoint List?

**Background**

I want to use a SharePoint List to record all of the training sessions that staff can complete. Some of those training sessions will require that other training sessions have already been completed (i.e. prerequisites).

I would like to use the Title column to record the name of each individual training session. I would then like to have a Choices column that allows multiple choices, so that I can select what training sessions already recorded in the Title column need to have been completed.

I have tried to search for similar solutions, but have been unsuccessful (possibly because I have used the wrong terminology).

Many thanks for any help that you can offer.

Comment: What version are you on?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the values of *Title* field in a choice column, you can create a [**lookup** column](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632) and link to the *Title* column in the current list.

--

Also if you are planning for “prerequisites” to populate choice values, you can build a cascading dropdown in the list to show/hide choice values based on another one.

Reference: [Cascading Dropdown in SharePoint List using Infopath Forms.](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/11/cascading-dropdown-using-infopath-forms-in-sharepoint-list.html) / [Cascading of Lookup Dropdown Fields on SharePoint 2013 and Office 365.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/cascading-of-lookup-dropdown-fields-on-sharepoint-2013-and-o/)